# Sharepoint Online, Power apps multiple forms on different screens, does not work

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need help, I have an application that needs to have multiple different screens for users to fill out a `` New Employees '' form I have the forms on different screens and this is causing me a serious problem, because in PowerApps, on each separate screen, It is a separate form control, so the goal is to make sure that while browsing from screen to screen, you are editing the same form and not creating a new one each time. Could anyone help me please? If this way it is not working for me, how do I make my application succeed?

Answer (score 1):

You can only create multiple screens in one form instead of using one form on multiple screens. You cannot share one control on multiple screens as it will lead to duplicate error.

To create a list form with multiple screens, please see the references below.

[Is it possible to split the Edit Form into multiple screens?](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-PowerApps-Formerly/Is-it-possible-to-split-the-Edit-Form-into-multiple-screens/td-p/243130)

[Display SharePoint Online List Columns in multiple screens in Microsoft PowerApps.](https://www.sharepointsky.com/powerapps-multiple-screens-sharepoint-list-columns/)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use one single form on multiple screen. I assume you want to Edit/Save all data just on one single submit Click to a list. Use custom controls create all fields, You will have to use a [Collection](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1241816/What-is-Collection-How-to-Manage-a-Collection-in-P) so that you go on collecting data from each screen and then use a [Patch()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-patch) function to save that collection to list.